# SVG file size limits for iOS Safari

Tags: ios, svg, mobile-safari

I am developing a mobile website which uses an IMG tag to display an SVG file. The SVG file is about 500 kB. The image renders OK in Android versions of Firefox and Chrome. However, in iOS Safari, I get only the dreaded tiny blue box with a question mark in it.

I am aware that there is a limit on the size of image files in iOS. According to Apple's [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15):

> The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM.
>
> That is, ensure that width * height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024 for devices with less than 256 MB RAM. Note that the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size of an image.

I imagine that there is some limit on the size of SVG files, but since they are vectorized, it doesn't really make sense to describe their size in terms of decoded pixels. Does anyone know how the limit on SVG files is determined?

P.S. When I put browse the SVG file directly instead of through an HTML page, I am able to view the image. I am also able to view the SVG file inside of an IFRAME. But not using the IMG tag.

Comment: Behind the scenes the browser will still render the vectors and treat it as a bitmap with the image tag, so the same constraints apply. What are the dimensions of your SVG? Do you have embedded data-uris within your SVG?

Comment: In my case, the size of the rendered SVG file is determined from the the dimensions of the viewport. On an iPhone, it would be something like 600x600. On an iPad, it would be more like 1500x1500. By my calculations, these dimensions still conform to the limits I posted above.

Comment: Yep, those dimensions shouldn't get you into trouble, so you can discard that. However, 500 KB for a vector image is way too much, do you have bitmap images embedded?

Comment: I agree that 500 KB is big. There are no bitmaps, but it is a very complex image. There is a lot of detail, but most of it is only visible when the user is zoomed in.

Comment: Do these limits still apply to more recent versions of iOS Safari?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made some test SVG files of varying sizes. They look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="2000" height="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="100" y="100" font-size="50">2000x2000</text>
</svg>
```

Using BrowserStack to emulate iPhone 5 and the 3rd Gen iPad, I found that the breakdown point is somewhere between 2200x2200 and 2400x2400 pixels. The 5 megapixel limit corresponds to an image that is 2289x2289, so this is consistent with [Duopixel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048332/svg-file-size-limits-for-ios-safari#comment24655496_17048332) stating that the rendered size is what matters.

Comment: It's worth noting that it must be the total area, not just width / height, because I had an SVG spritemap that was 400px tall and was fine with a width of 12,000px, but once it went over 12,000px it broke.  I reformatted it for square format and it ended up being 2886px x 2405px, which produce the same result as the 400px x 12,000px SVG.