# SVG in iOS browser

Tags: ios, mobile, svg

I'm making sure a site I'm working on is mobile optimized.  I've used SVG icons in many places, and they render no problem on iOS devices.  I'm using two more complicated SVG images that I exported from Adobe Illustrator, and they render everywhere except on iOS browsers. They do not render on iOS for Chrome nor Safari.  I figured it was something to do with my export settings in Illustrator, but after all my attempts trying different exports, nothing seems to work.  Any thoughts?

[Here's a paste of one of the SVGs that will not render](http://pastebin.com/Nzx9eunH)

Comment: glad I was able to help, btw, very cool logo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [SVG file size limits for iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048332/svg-file-size-limits-for-ios-safari)

The rendering size of the SVG might be too large for the `iOS` specs.